# Update view using function based view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

How can I pass an object into a model form to pre-populate the field when the page is rendered? I want to do something similar to the build in Django UpdateView class based view but with a function based view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just get the object from model and pass that object as instance to the form. Then pass the form to the template. Write your view like below example.

```
def func(request, id):

    object = Model.objects.get(id=id)
    form = ModelForm(instance=object)

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried something....

```
def approveform(request, pk):

    if pk:

        form = Admission.objects.get(pk=pk)

        p = Admission.objects.get(pk=pk)

        form = ApproveForm(instance=form)

    return render(
        request,
        'Automation/formapprove.html',
        {
            'year': datetime.now().year,
            'form': form,
            'test': p,
        }
    )
```

Comment: What will happen if `pk` is `False/None`? Your variables `form`, `p` are defined globally?