# Django - Form Not Updating

Tags: python, django

I’m creating a profile page in my web application & I have a form to when the  user makes a form submission I need the data from the form to update in admin from the current logged in user.

The data populates in the admin however new listings keep repeating every time the user submits a form. I need the the data to update only. Screenshot attached.

How do I execute this correctly with my current code?

The Custom User Model I’m using is located in `from users.models import CustomUser` if that helps.

Any help i gladly appreciated, Cheers

[image]

[image]

## user_profile/models

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from users.models import CustomUser

class Listing (models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    cc_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    cc_expiration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    cc_cvv = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#    objects = ListingManager()

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=CustomUser)
```

## user_profile/views.py

```
def change_view(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":  # checking if request is POST or Not
        # if its a post request, then its checking if the form is valid or not
        if form.is_valid():
            listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
            listing_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance
            listing_instance.save() # calling 'save()' method of model
            return redirect("myaccount")

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile 
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)
```

## user_profile/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from user_profile.forms import HomeForm
from users.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm

from user_profile.models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser


# Register models here.
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'created', 'updated', 'user']
    list_filter = ['name', 'zip_code', 'created', 'updated', 'user']

admin.site.register(Listing, UserProfileAdmin)
```

**html**

```
{% block content %}
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.errors }}   
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.address }}
{{ form.zip_code }}
{{ form.mobile_number }}
{{ form.image }}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success btn-round btn-extend" type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-favorite-outline6"></i>Submit</button>
</form>    
{% endblock content %}
```

## user_profile/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

from .views import change_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('myaccount/', change_view, name='myaccount'),
]
```

**settings**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 pass customer Id after request and use url path as mentioned below
```

**For View Function Change**

```
def upload_data(request, pk):
    order = ModelName.objects.get(id=pk)
    form= FormName(instance=order)
    request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormName(request.POST, instance=order)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('url/')
    return render(request, ' url/', {'form':form})


**For URLS.py**    

post('functionName/<str:pk>',views.functionName,name='Function Name'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `listing_instance = form.save()` to

```
listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That didn't work my friend. When I made the change the same issue occurs. Any other ideas?

Comment: remove this line `form = HomeForm()`

Comment: Just tried that & no luck, same thing happened. Also, the values that were in the input fields didn't disappear when I submitted the form :/

Comment: The data you submit save twice? If that please comment your change according to me.

Comment: Yes, I made your changes and the same issue still occurs my friend.

Comment: can you comment what you chnages?

Comment: I tested your suggestion by removing `form = HomeForm()` and also tested changing `listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)`, with no luck :/

Comment: is your form getting existing data?

Comment: Yes, in admin the form submission keeps repeating with multiple listings.. I want the form to update only and not repeat when the logged in user makes a form submission. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in default admin. I know in general way

Comment: What's the general way?

Comment: My implementation https://github.com/shafikshaon/mess_balance/blob/master/meals/views.py#L54

Comment: Is there a way updating a form without using UpdateView?

Comment: you can use function based view instead of this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842708/update-view-using-function-based-view

Comment: I'll continue troubleshooting and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the problem is that you are not differentiating the request types. You should handle the get and post request separately in your view. So the view should be like this:

```
def change_view(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profile = Listing.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=user_profile)
    if request.method == "POST":  # checking if request is POST or Not
        # if its a post request, then its checking if the form is valid or not
        if form.is_valid():
            listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
            listing_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance
            listing_instance.save() # calling 'save()' method of model
            return redirect("success-url-path")

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)
```

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give this a try later today and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and no luck. I still get the form submission to repeat instead of update. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you see any error in form? Does new item gests stored in DB? BTW what is the success url you are using?

Comment: No errors my friend. I'm using the same page that the form is getting submitted on so it's `myaccount`. I'm new to django but the item gets stored in the django admin so I'm assuming it's getting stored in the DB?

Comment: can you please update the question with your updated code, urls.py and `myaccount.html`?

Comment: I just added `urls.py`, `myaccount.html` and updated `views.py`. Please let me know what you think my friend.

Comment: do you have any other urls which you can redirect to after successful form submission? atleast for debugging purpose? maybe you can redirect to adminsite by `return redirect("admin")` to see if the form is successfully submitted

Comment: I mean, after a successful submission, if the page redirected to the same page(myaccount) again, then you will see an empty form after each submission.

Comment: yes the form is empty after a successful form submission however all the data in the django admin gets added multiple times instead of updating for the current logged in user. I added another snapshot of my django admin if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186572/discussion-between-spidey677-and-ruddra).